# Remote debugging using Eclipse - How to set breakpoints?

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212563/how-to-debug-large-server-side-distributed-java-application) question about how to debug server side applications and I think I was looking for [Java remote Debugging](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/#N101A1).

I have configured my server side startup script:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2G -server -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n"
```

By this, I assume the remote java app should be available on localhost:1044 (try it first using localhost)

But, what do I do next? I have configured the debug options to the class to be debugged via  `Run-->Debug Configurations`. But it asks me to click Debug. But my class does not have a main() method.

Say, I want to debug `getValue()` in `Methods.java`, now `getValue()` is invoked from a client (via tcp).

So, how do I attach the java process to eclipse remote debugger when that method is invoked? Am I missing out on something basic about remote debugging?

UPDATE: (I can see this in my debug view, that means, the remote app is connected and in the debug mode, now how do I put a breakpoint in the file where I want)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the line below:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n
```

to run eclipse in debug mode

For eclipse, click on debug as icon > debug configurations > add a new remote java application > change the project to the project that you need and port to 1044 and click on apply and debug.

Put your breakpoint and access the remote application

Comment: 1. I started my server to debug on localhost, 2. start eclipse as you said. 3. did the debug configuration. But how do I invoke my server code?

Comment: From your original question, assuming you set everything up correctly, you can simply put a breakpoint on your server code and run your client to interact with your server code. When it hits that code, you will see it on eclipse. BTW, as soon as you create your remote java application debugging in eclipse, switch to debug perspective and you should see that its connected to your server in the debug window

Comment: yup, please see my updated question. So, when I try to debug my client, the debugger should jump to the server code?

Comment: Thanks for the update. You would need your Server application source code in your workspace and put the breakpoint there (where Method.java is).

Comment: the client use a client jar file (stub for the server app). so, how will the request route to the actual source code of the server? (i have the server source code in my workspace and it's in debug mode as you can see in the screenshot) +1 for the help! Thanks! :)

Comment: So in you web application(assuming it is a webapp), you when you use your client, you invoke a class on your webapp. lets assume its a.b.c.Method, since you are running your webapp in debug mode(those agent lib and stuff that you added when your server was started), it will check if there are connected debug clients and will route those request there first before proceeding(in our case eclipse is connected to the debugged webapp). It will then look for a.b.c.Method in our workspace and since you put a breakpoint under a.b.c.Method, it will stop there.

Comment: well, I am trying to debug a distributed server project voldemort (like apache cassandra). The client have 2 methods available: put() and get() and I want to jump inside the put() code on the server side when put() is called on the client side.

Comment: it does not matter where you call it as long as your server gets the request and your eclipse is connected to it. As long as that code it called, you will be able to break on it.